# Disconnect logined remote desktop user by command

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, remote-desktop, terminal-services

How disconnect a logged RD user from the computer by command?
I want to do exactly occurred in task manager users list:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2015/07/how-to-logoff-remote-user-via-cmd.html)

Essentially it boils down to finding the appropriate session ID via `QWinsta` (or `query session`) and then use `Logoff` to shutdown that specific session

[image: Query and logoff session]

Comment: and tsdiscon [sessionId] for disconnect session

Comment: tanks @tomcater,this worked.